# AngularJS - Using an external Factory for a $http GET Request - How to return the result properly?

Tags: angularjs, http, service, get, angularjs-scope

After a few tries, I am now able to access the external service factory (was told it's a good practise to decentralise it) to retrieve product data and display them in my view.

At the moment I am passing the `$scope` to the function, which seems kind of ugly (especially if you add further CRUD methods).

Is there a better / more appropriate way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

At the moment I use it as seen below (which is working):

### **services.js**

```
angular.module('services', [])
.constant("baseDataUrl", "http://localhost:55451/api/")
.factory('sportsstoreService', function ($http, baseDataUrl) {

    var serviceApi = {};

    serviceApi.getProducts = function ($scope) {
         $http({ method: 'GET', url: baseDataUrl + 'product' }).
         success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.data.products = data;
         }).
         error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             // called asynchronously if an error occurs
             // or server returns response with an error status.
         });
    };

    return serviceApi;        
});
```

### **sportsstore.js**

```
angular.module("sportsStore")
    .controller("sportsStoreCtrl", function ($scope, sportsstoreService) {

        $scope.data = {};

        sportsstoreService.getProducts($scope);

});
```

Comment: Take a look at angular `$resource` service (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). You could return in your sportService factory the new instance of object returned by `$resource` and then use it like `SportService.get()`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an factory which will return angular's `$resource` object. Angular `$resource` object has default actions:

```
 { 'get':    {method:'GET'},
    'save':   {method:'POST'},
    'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
    'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
    'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

but you can extend them with your own custom actions. Read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource

There is an example:

```
.factory('SportsStoreService', function ($http, baseDataUrl) {
    var serviceApiCustomMethods={};

    serviceApiCustomMethods.getSimillarItems ={
        method: 'GET',
        url: baseDataUrl + 'product/simillar/:id',
        isArray: true
    };

    return $resource(baseDataUrl + 'product/:id',{}, serviceApiCustomMethods);

});
```

And usage:

```
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope,SportsStoreService){

    SportsStoreService.query(function(response){
        //success
    },function(response){
        //error
    });

    SportsStoreService.get({id:'123'},function(response){
        //success
    },function(response){
        //error
    });

    SportsStoreService.getSimillarItems({id:'456',additionalGetParam: 5, anotherParam: desc},function(response){
      //success
    }); /*url's :id will be replacad with given id value because it matches url param in method declaration. 
       Rest of params will be added as GET params - ?additionalGetParam=5&anotherParam=desc*/       
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your service so that the function returns a promise, like so:

```
serviceApi.getProducts = function () {
  return $http
    .get(baseDataUrl + 'product')
    .then(
      function success (response) {
        return response.data;
      },
      function error (reason) {
        // Do something!
      }
    );
};
```

and then in your controller:

```
$scope.data = sportsstoreService.getProducts();
```

For info on promises:

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-promises

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-chained-promises

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q